# RestSharp AddParameter

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I want to make a RestSharp request and the following desired result is like :

```
tes = {
"paye": "0",
"type": "0",
"lines": [
   {
      "desc": "1",
      "note": "10",
   },
   {
      "desc": "2",
      "note": "20",
   },
   {
      "desc": "3",
      "note": "30",
   }
]
}
```

so I make a request like this :

```
 var client = new RestClient(url);
 var request = new RestRequest("tes", Method.POST);
 request.AddParameter("paye", 0);
 request.AddParameter("type", 0);
```

and the problem is how to finish the lines[] part?

Thank you

Comment: You should use a class, assign values and then use a `jsonserializer` to serialize it and send through request.

Answer (score 0):

Create class like :

```
class tes {
//include all the properties here
}
```

Serialize the object and pass it in parameter with the RestSharp request.

Comment: Was tried to serialize using restsharp addjsonbody method, but the problem is parameter name become ”application/json" which give the result as bad parameter name. Have no idea how to customize the parameter name